# how to save two colony of data in two seperated vector in c++

Tags: c++, image

If I have this 2d array which contains two colony of nonzero data, how can I transfer all index of thoes nonzero values in two seperated vector. one for the indices of all nonzero values which are in the left side, and one for thoes which are in the right side?

```
{1,0,0,0,1,0} 
{1,1,0,0,1,1}
{1,0,0,0,0,0}
```

this is what I have done until now:

I used for-loop but I feel it is not correct:

```
for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
for(int j=0; j < height; j++){
if(Maps[i][j] > 0 || Maps[i+1][j] > 0 || Maps[i-1][j] > 0 || Maps[i][j+1] > 0 || Maps[i][j-1] > 0){ 
     row = j / width;
     col = j % width;
    }
}
```

and I tried to use switch-case but i did not continue with that since it seemed rubbish!

```
for(int i=0 ; i<width; i++){
   for(int j=0 ; j<height; j++){ 

      switch(){
          case (Maps[i][j] > 0):
             row = j / width;
         col = j % width;
         PIndAmp.push_back(std::make_pair(row,col));  
             break; 
          case (Maps[i][j] > 0 && Maps[i][j+1] > 0):
                   for(Maps[i][j] > 0){
                       row = j / width;
                       col = j % width;
                       PIndAmp.push_back(std::make_pair(row,col));
                     }
                   for(Maps[i][j+1] > 0){
                       row = j+1 / width;
                       col = j % width;
                       PIndAmp.push_back(std::make_pair(row,col));
                     }
                                     break; 

    }
}
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename S>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<F, S>& t) {
    return os << '(' << t.first << ',' << t.second << ')';
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (auto& el : vec) {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned int width = 6;
    constexpr unsigned int height = 3;
    const unsigned int array[height][width] = {
        {1,0,0,0,1,0},
        {1,1,0,0,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0},
    };
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> colonies;
    colonies left;
    colonies right;
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        colonies * vector = &left;
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            const unsigned int value = array[y][x];
            if (value == 0) {
                vector = &right;
            } else {
                vector->push_back(std::make_pair(y, x));
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Right: " << std::endl << right << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Left: " << std::endl << left << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
+ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
+ ./a.out
Right: 
(0,4) (1,4) (1,5) 
Left: 
(0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (2,0)
```

You can run it online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8fedf55dba3f598)

Comment: It's hard to understand from the question what you would like.  I can modify the answer to answer your question.

Comment: Nope, the 9's on the left and the 9's on the right are part of two different colonies.

Comment: @Raja I'm not sure I can answer the question - I don't know what a colony is! :(  Is it locality based?  Do you have a link to information about colonies?

Comment: thanks for your time...
I want to have something like this at the vector called left:
(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(2,0)

Comment: Well, if you see his array, the 1's on the left are separated by 0's from the 1's on the right. Each of the group of 1's is a colony.

Comment: ...and something like this in vector called right:
(0,4)(1,4)(1,5)

Comment: I guess that you'd rather implement something like connected components though, that's what we do in our background segmentation algorithm.  The above code won't work in different cases, just for the data set provided in the question. Edit: just refreshed @Raja has answered with the same...

Comment: :) i was just going to say it doesnt work for [this case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e34ac14f1c64fe83)

Comment: @Matt Clarsson: Thanks a lot.
what I am trying now is to change your code to make it work for every 2d arrays...
seems new story :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic application of [Breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (or) [Depth first search.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

The exact problem would be [Finding connected components in a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29)

Comment: Thanks for the links...this is exactly what I want.
there is a Pseudocode inside one of them. I know its Pseudocode, but I get problem when I try to write its code in c++!

Comment: The key is really the data structure you use. Instead of complicating the problem via iteration and recursion, all you need is a stack for DFS and a queue for BFS.